# Switching between event handlers of dispatcherTimer tick event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events

in my application I have dispatcherTimer and few eventHandlers which I use on dispatcherTimer.Tick event:

```
dt.Tick += myEventHandler1
```

when I want to switch event handlers of the tick I use sth like this:

```
dt.Tick -= myEventHandler1
dt.Tick += myEventHandler2
```

Is it correct way ?

Should I check if dt.Tick is not null before that ?

Also what is the best way to remove all eventHandlers from dt.Tick event ?

I use .net 3.5

thank You very much for help

Answer (score 2):

You need not check for nullity before adding or removing an event handler however you *do* need to check for nullity before raising the event.

In order to remove all of the event handlers you will have to remove the event handlers manually as you have already or write a function to do so automatically using reflection.

```
private void RemoveHandlers(DispatcherTimer dispatchTimer)
{
    var eventField = dispatchTimer.GetType().GetField("Tick",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var eventDelegate = (Delegate) eventField.GetValue(dispatchTimer);
    var invocatationList = eventDelegate.GetInvocationList();

    foreach (var handler in invocatationList)
        dispatchTimer.Tick -= ((EventHandler) handler);
}
```

In the context of a delegate you could simply assign `null` in order to remove all of the handlers from the chain however events inherently prevent this.

Comment: intellisense says: the event tick can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Comment: @gruber Yes, you won't be able to just assign a delegate to an event, it would need to be just a delegate (which would mean creating your own `Timer`, or wrapper over a timer), as the answer says.  In this context though you don't need to do that, you can just do what you're doing.

Comment: @Servy I edited the question since his comment. It was me who made the mistake originally.

Comment: @gruber My bad. There was a small amount of confusion with my original answer but have since updated the answer. Does this answer your question?